# Table View inside Collection View Xib Cell Bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my application:

1. I have Collection view with paging - 1 cell per screen,
2. There are 3 cells in total that are created in xib and set in collection view as one cell - one section
3. Two cells have nested table views, first cell is working fine, second is not:

Small code example of not working cell:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    print("Cell loaded")

    addButton.setTitle(TextData.TrackScreen.Log.addButton, for: .normal)
    userLogsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ReloadLogsData"), object: nil)

    userLogsTableView.dataSource = self
    userLogsTableView.delegate = self

    userLogsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "WrongName", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "WrongName")
    userLogsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "WrongName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "WrongName") }
```

My problem is - this code as well as all other table view code is not working at all, even though I have everything setup. 
It even doesn't gives me error - wrong cell registered. Looks like it just ignores for some reason what I have typed. This is very strange, as table view in previous cell is working fine and I'm using same code.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Here's link to sample project - https://github.com/tarastomchuk/SO_Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my problem was that I was using grouped table view and if you pass empty data - it doesn't work at all